# Proving first integral defines a locally topological conjugate vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems

> Let $M$ be a n dimension manifold, $X\in\mathscr{X}^1(M)$ and $f$ a first integral for the flux generated by $X$. Assuming $f$ is of  $C^1$ class and $Df(p)\neq 0$, show that exists a neigborhood of $p$ such that $X$ is topologically conjugate of a flux of the form $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{n-1},0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> **Definition**: A first integral with real values $f:U\subset M\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a first integral for a flux $(\phi_t)_t$ if:
>
> **i**) f is flux invariant
>
> **ii**) f is not constant in open subsets of $U$.

Attempted proof:

Consider $F$ the graphic:

$F:M\to \mathbb{R}^n\\(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},\alpha)\to(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1},f(x_1,..x_{n-1}))$

I could apply the implicit function theorem to assure me a open neighbourhood  $V\subset M$ for $p_1,...,p_2$ if I can assure that $\det Df(p)\neq 0$(so that $Df(p)$ is a linear isomorphism). However the question only concedes me the fact $Df(p)\neq 0$ not the determinant.

**Question**:

**1)** Is there any way to conlude $\det Df(p)\neq 0$? Or should I search for another way to prove the assertion?

**2)** Can I subtract a constant $\alpha$ to get $(y_1,...y_{n-1},0)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Again you really need to study the implicit function theorem (or the inverse function theorem). Hint: why should you take $f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ in the last component and somewhere else? By the way, what is the peculiar $\alpha$ in the definition of the map $F$?

Comment: @JohnB            $f(x_1...x_n)=\alpha$ I have already studied the both theorems and their respective proofs, but that does not tell me how should I prove that $Df(p)\neq 0$ is a isomorphism. For that I would need the determinant.